# PHP fails to load MySQL modules - "libmysqlclient.so.18" error

Tags: mysql, php, percona

I'm installing a new CentOS 6.4 box, to move my websites over from my current 5.9 box.

I've ended up with Apache 2.2.4, PHP 5.4.16 (via "powerstack" repo), and Percona 5.6.13 (via percona's own repo).

**I was briefly on PHP 5.3.3 via the standard repo, and everything worked then.  It's only since moving to PHP 5.4.16 that it's broken.  But I'd like to fix it rather than step back down to 5.3.3**

Anyway, when I try to start apache, I get these errors:

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: symbol mysql_options, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0

    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: symbol client_errors, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0

    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: symbol mysql_options, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas?  Do I need to compile the modules from source or something?  Just give me a pointer in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install php from [ius community repo](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/). Should work without any problem.

Comment: That does indeed seem to have fixed it.  Why though?  Were there problems with 5.4.16, or is the "powerstack" repo suspect?  Or is it just a case of "something had gone wrong, do a reinstall and it'll probably fix itself"?

Comment: (although I opted to use their "stable" branch rather than the "testing" one you linked to)

Comment: Yes, you were right. I just thought you want php-5.5 rather than php-5.4, which available in the test repo. I have updated my answer.